# Android Database onUpgrade blocking UI Thread

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My app has a pretty big database, especially one of the tables - it has like 2 million entities. In the next app release we are doing a huge update - dropping one of the columns and replacing it with another one. For the biggest table this takes ~ 13 sec.

The problem is even though i have put this update in a background thread(still it is in the onUpgrade method of the SQLLiteDatabase), it still blocks the UI thread and causes an android os popup to appear - prompting to either kill the app or wait.
Is the onUpgrade method actually blocking the UI thread, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's a bug in your code. Please post the background thread setup and invocation part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use StrictMode API to detect the exact cause of the UI thread blocking.

I would recommend you to a service and initiate this db upgrade if it's going to be huge one, also provide a loading screen if you don't want see the UI immediately.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There was actually another database process that was blocking the UI thread. I managed to identify the problem using the StrictMode API. Thanks @albeee